# Can i store and access iphotos library on external hard drive (and still have it backup to my cloud network)?

Tags: photos, external-disk, setup-assistant

I have two questions regarding Apple photos library.

- Can I store my large Photos library on an external HDD?
- Is it possible to set this HDD to backup via my computer to the same local network attached storage that my computer backs up too?

Notes: I am using a 2015 MacBook Pro running Big Sur, I am backing up to a NAS drive using time machine

Comment: Usually its best to only ask one question at a time, since backing up and storing a photoslibrary on an external device are two distinctively different questions. Also, you say iPhoto, however, SteveChambers and I both assumed you mean photos since iPhoto is becoming quite old and you did not mention macOS version neither what macModel so its hard to guess. Further, you don't specify the backup method, which is why I assumed you are using the TimeMachine

Comment: This is (possibly) an exception to the rule for one question per question. The answer will be throw more drives at your backup so you always have one. iCloud or any cloud sync is never a backup since one mistake on the computer syncs to the cloud or vice versa. I'd want two Time Machine backups that rotate to cover a large library - unless you archive your photos in addition to managing them - you'll never get them back due to fire or mistake and only one backup volume in play...

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those "fun" non-discoverable Apple settings that you would only know if you knew about this setting already. Yah catch-22. Anyway.

1. Copy the photoslibrary file to the drive you want to store it on.
2. While holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, launch the Photos.app

Instead of Photos.app opening, you will get something like this

[image: Photos.app Library Chooser]

3. Click on the Other Library button and point it to the photos library you just copied to your external drive.

It will open that file and set it as the default, so that the next time you open photos.app it will open that file again. You can verify that by renaming or moving the one in the old default location and launching photos.app normally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can transfer the photo library to an external drive or NAS and still back it up.

You can simply copy and paste your current library (usually the `.photoslibrary` package is located in `/user/Photos/`) to your external storage device. Make sure to not interrupt the copy process, because restarting the copy process means you will lose all progress (unless you use e.g. rsync).

To make sure which photoslibrary you are opening follow Steves answer.

---

Backing up the library also still works e.g. with TimeMachine. Just go into `settings` -> `TimeMachine` -> `options` -> select the external device -> hit the `-` sign. This will backup the whole external device, but you can exclude all other files by hitting the `+` sign in that same view and selecting everything except the photoslibrary.

---

You didn't ask how many drives are needed for Time Machine but the answer is more than one. Set up multiple drives in rotation and keep one off site if you can. Having one connected regularly is awesome, but more destinations will save your photos if disaster strikes.