# How to download entire iCloud photo library to external drive attached to my MacBook

Tags: icloud, backup, photos

I have a large iCloud photo library (60K + images).  I want to keep my iCloud library as it is and make a copy of it onto an external drive (attached to my MacBook, running Big Sur).  What is the easiest way to do this please?

Comment: Do you have all the pictures/photos already downloaded on your Mac?

Comment: No, they are only on iCloud, I think...

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Once your library is safely moved to the external, change the setting in Photos to download all images.

1. [Can i store and access iphotos library on external hard drive (and still have it backup to my cloud network)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/414756/5472)
2. https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/download-photos-to-your-mac-from-icloud-phtfa50fd1ec/mac
3. Verify you’re backing up your Mac and the external drive
4. Wait a week and then delete the old photos library from internal storage so you can free up that space and not have two libraries and metadata hanging around

Apple documents step 1 as well - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201517